# Make portions of email body bold

Tags: html, vba, outlook

I am using Excel VBA code to send email via Outlook.

How do I make specific text which is fixed in the code, bold:

`Event/Activity`, `Department`, `Date of Event`, `Description`.

```vb
Dim wStat As Range, i As Long
Dim dam As Object

For Each wStat In Range("I2", Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    If wStat.Value = "Overdue" Then
        i = wStat.Row
        Set dam = CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(0)
        dam.To = Range("F" & i).Value
        dam.Cc = Range("G" & i).Value
        dam.Subject = Range("C" & i).Value
        dam.htmlBody = "    Hi " & Range("E" & i).Value & "," & vbCr & vbCr & vbCr & _
          " This is to remind you that the " & Range("C" & wStat.Row).Value & _
          " is overdue. The details are as follows:" & vbCr & vbCr & _
          " Event / Activity : " & Range("C" & i).Value & vbCr & vbCr & _
          " Department : " & Range("D" & i).Value & vbCr & vbCr & _
          " Date of event : " & Range("A" & i).Value & vbCr & vbCr & _
          " Description : " & Range("H" & i).Value & vbCr & vbCr & _
          " Please update your status as soon as possible! Thanks." & vbCr & vbCr & vbCr & _
          " Best Regards," & vbCr & _
          " XX Department"
        '
        dam.Display
    End If
Next
MsgBox "Reminder sent"
End Sub
```

Comment: it's just basic HTML as part of your string... like this `"<b> Date of event : </b>"` - Add a `<b>` to "turn on" bold and then use `</b>` to "turn off" the bold.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response and it's working. However, the problem I have now is that it is ignoring my vbCr codes. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: dont use `vbCr` - that is not HTML, you have to use HTML... for line breaks, use `<br>` inside of your string - `"<b> Date of<br>event : </b>"`

Comment: https://riptutorial.com/html/example/1715/bold--italic--and-underline

Answer (score 0):

The HTMLBody property of Outlook items sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. The `HTMLBody` property should be an HTML syntax string and well formed. Otherwise, you may end up with a wrong look and feel of the document. Setting the `HTMLBody` property will always update the `Body` property immediately.

```
Sub CreateHTMLMail() 
 'Creates a new email item and modifies its properties. 
 Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem 
 'Create email item 
 Set objMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
 With objMail 
 'Set body format to HTML 
 .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML 
 .HTMLBody = _ 
 "<HTML><BODY>Enter the <b>bold</b> message text here. </BODY></HTML>"
 .Display 
 End With 
End Sub
```

Here is a sample HTML markup which can help with marking the text as required:

```
<b>This text is bold</b>
<strong>This text is strong</strong>
<i>This text is italic</i>
<h2>HTML <mark>Marked</mark> Formatting</h2>
<p>This is <sup>superscripted</sup> text.</p>
```